# where to store texts in database separated by paragraphs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a website where I want to publish my novels. I decided to create it with node.js because the interaction with the chapters would be much better.

but now I'm at an impasse, I tried to store the data via file.txt, but the paragraphs are not organized correctly.

so I would like to know the best way to make this site. I'm using handlebars to create each chapter, I don't know if this would be the right way.

I intend to send the text in the textarea and try to somehow add it to the handlebars chapter file. if this form is not suitable, please tell me what kind of database to use and whether it is necessary to make several handlebars files for each chapter.

**ChapterController.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')


const pasta = path.join(__dirname, '../views/chapters')



module.exports = class ChaptersController {
    static async chapters(req, res) {
        fs.readdir(pasta, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err) 
            } else {
                const links = files.map((file) => {
                    return { nome: path.basename(file, '.handlebars')}
                })
               
                res.render('chapters', {links})
            }
        })
        
    }
    
}
```

**HomeController.js**

```
module.exports = class HomeController {
    static async home(req, res) {
        res.render('home');
    }

}
```

**Routes chapters.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const ChaptersController = require('../controller.js/ChaptersController')


router.get('/chapters', ChaptersController.chapters)

module.exports = router
```

**Routes Home.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const HomeController = require('../controller.js/HomeController')


router.get('/', HomeController.home)


module.exports = router
```

**views/layouts/main.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/chapters">Capítulos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>``
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

**views/chapters.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/chapters">Capítulos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')


const home = require('./routes/Home')
const chapters = require('./routes/Chapters')

const app = express()

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.engine())
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended:true,
    }),
)



app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use('/', home)
app.use('/', chapters)

app.listen(3000)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqVyG.png)